# Prometheus in docker container showing remote node is up even after node is down

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, prometheus, monitoring

Here is part of my docker compose file:

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./data/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - ./data/alerting/alertmanager_rules.yml:/etc/prometheus/alertmanager_rules.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    depends_on:
      - alertmanager
    networks:
      - monitor-net
```

this is prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
  evaluation_interval: 1m


alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ['alertmanager:9093']

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  - "alertmanager_rules.yml"




scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'dev_server_prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 30s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prometheus:9090']

      

  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 30s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['x.x.x.x:9100']
        labels:
          instance: "production"
```

I opened the 9100 port in remote host but if i remove the 9100 port in remote host, prometheus still showing that host is up (i waited for hours) and showing wrong metrics may be it is collectig from cache.
But the weird things is if i restart the docker compose prometheus can detect that host is down and alertmanager is also sending notification of that.

Can someone please tell me what is happeing and a workaround of this issue.

I am using Ubuntu: 20.04 & docker version: 23.0.1 & Docker Compose version:v2.16.0

*Observation:*

> I am running the node in aws.So instead of blocking the port if i keep
> the port open (Using aws console's inbound request option) but stop the node exporter service, prometheus is
> responding properly and also alerting works.

Although the problem is resolved for now still I'm curious to know why this is happening, i don't have much idea on networking.

Comment: It is not clear how you're closing port, but I believe it would be safe to assume that you actually didn't close it.

Comment: Thanks @markalex for asking.I've also edited question. In aws ec2  security console's inbound  request a port can be opened or deleted if exists.Thats how i'm allowing ports to be exposed or blocked right now.

Comment: In that case this is more of AWS question than prometheus question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use telnet command to verify if a remote host's port is closed?